# C# WinForms DataBindings Not Working When Tabbing Through Controls

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I'm having an issue with `DataBindings` in C# WinForms when using `tab` to switch between controls. I've created a sample WinForms application to show the issue. Here is the code:

```
PersonModel person { get; set; } = new PersonModel();

private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Create test person, populate with values
    person = new PersonModel { FirstName = "Sammy", LastName = "Smith", UserType = "Admin", Age = 29, Gender = "Female", EducationYears = 4};
    CreateBindings();
}

private void CreateBindings()
{
    txtFirstName.DataBindings.Add("Text", person, "FirstName");
    txtLastName.DataBindings.Add("Text", person, "LastName");
    cmbUserType.DataBindings.Add("Text", person, "UserType", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
    cmbGender.DataBindings.Add("Text", person, "Gender", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
    nudAge.DataBindings.Add("Value", person, "Age", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
    nudEducationYears.DataBindings.Add("Value", person, "EducationYears", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
}

private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(person.ToString());
}

class PersonModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; } = "";
    public string LastName { get; set; } = "";
    public string UserType { get; set; } = "Read-only";
    public string Gender { get; set; } = "Unspecified";
    public int Age { get; set; } = 0;
    public int EducationYears { get; set; } = 0;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        string message = "";
        message += $"First name: {this.FirstName}{Environment.NewLine}";
        message += $"Last name: {this.LastName}{Environment.NewLine}";
        message += $"User type: {this.UserType}{Environment.NewLine}";
        message += $"Gender: {this.Gender}{Environment.NewLine}";
        message += $"Age: {this.Age.ToString()}{Environment.NewLine}";
        message +=$"Education (years): {this.EducationYears.ToString()}";
        return message;
    }
}
```

The UI is just a few TextBoxes, ComboBoxes, and NumericUpDown controls that are bound to the `PersonModel` `person`. When I click through the UI with my mouse and change the values in the controls, the program works as expected: when I click `Save`, the `ToString()` method of `PersonModel` shows that all the properties have been updated as expected. However, when I restart the application and tab through the controls, the DataBinding for the comboboxes (for `Gender` and `User Type`) do not update the values in `person`. When I tab down to `Save` and hit `Enter`, the `ToString()` method shows the `Gender` and `UserType` properties in `person` have not changed.

When clicking through the UI, all the input values are properly reflected in `person`:

[image: Clicking through controls]

When tabbing through the UI, the values input for `Gender` and `UserType` do not get applied to their respective properties (note that the default values of `Admin` and `Female` remain unchanged):

[image: Tabbing through controls]

What is the problem here? Why do the databindings work as expected when clicking through the UI, but when tabbing through they do not? Do I need to choose a different `PropertyName` for the comboboxes in the databinding? If `Text` is not the right `PropertyName` to use in the databinding, why does `Text` work without issue when clicking through the controls?

EDIT: The comment from LarsTech solved my problem, but to the rest of the community, I would still like to hear any thoughts as to why using `tab` to navigate my form does not update databindings while clicking through the form does. I know that the [focus events differ when when using tab as opposed to clicking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.gotfocus?view=netframework-4.7.2). However, since all the same events are still fired, I don't know if this would explain the difference.

Comment: `cmbUserType.DataBindings.Add("Text"`  Text is probably not the property you want for a ComboBox.  Try SelectedItem or SelectedValue if you have a DataSource and ValueMember setup.

Comment: @LarsTech hm, I could have swore I tried `SelectedItem`, but I must not have because that works as expected, both for tabbing and for clicking. I guess I'm just confused as to why `Text` works when clicking, but not when tabbing.

Comment: Not sure I know what you mean by tab vs click.  Why would either action have any affect here?

Comment: @LarsTech because one works and the other does not with the `Text` property binding. When I use the `tab` key to switch between controls, the `Text` property binding does not update the `person` object with the ComboBox values. When I click between controls using my mouse, the `Text` property binding does update the `person` object with the ComboBox values.

Comment: @LarsTech, your comment solved my issue, so if you would post it as an answer I will mark it as the answer and upvote.

Comment: If you have an answer, go ahead and post it yourself.  I'm still not sure how the tabbing thing was an issue for you, other than, data usually doesn't get committed until "after" the control loses focus.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by LarsTech in the comments, changing the `DataBinding` `Property` from `Text` to `SelectedItem` causes the form to work as expected. When navigating through the form using `tab`, the `DataBinding` updates the bound property just as if I was clicking through the form.

I still don't know why using `tab` to navigate through the form does not update the `person` object when the binding property is `Text`, especially when clicking through the form causes the binding to update as expected. As stated in the original question, am still curious to hear why there is such a difference in behavior. If anyone has any insight I'd be curious to hear why this is the case.